# Can I use Typescript intellisense in a JS project for custom modules?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working in a JS code base but I wanted to add declarations for some complex entities in the application. This is so I have them as auto-completable in my VS Code.

This works for dependencies that have TS declarations so I presume it can be done.

I tried the following in a `d.ts` file beside my `.js` file`

```
import "./useUserContext";

declare module "./useUserContext" {
  interface User {
    user: {
      uid: string;
    },
  }

  export default function useUserContext(): User;
}
```

There is sadly no possibility of converting this project to TS.

Comment: Remove `declare module "./useUserContext" {`, pulling its contents to file scope.

Comment: Thanks. I found it can also be done with JSDoc `
/**
 * @returns { [import("../../types").Auth] }
 */`.

Comment: True, but you don't need to

Comment: Yep, I prefer your way as it keeps the JS clean. Just leaving it for reference.